# Reduce sensitivity of mouse click detection

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouseevent, mouse-listeners

I've had this problem repeatedly over the years with AWT and Swing based interfaces: some mouse clicks events do not trigger mouseClicked in a MouseListener because the mouse moved at least one pixel during the click (which is most clicks with some mice). This is interpreted as a drag operation instead.
Is there a way to tell AWT/Swing to be a bit more permissive in its definition of a click?

Manually implementing a workaround is quite cumbersome if you want a full solution (if your components must also handle drag operations for instance):

1. Adding a unique MouseListener and MouseMotionListener to every component
2. Doing some sort of calculation of a click in mouseMoved, mouseDragged and mouseReleased (which requires measuring time elapsed, distance traveled...)
3. Forwarding the "fixed" mouse events to a new mouse input interface implemented by the components

There's got to be a better way! I'm hoping for a global setting but I just can't find one...

### Related posts

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20493509/drag-threshold-for-some-components-too-low
- [Making a component less sensitive to Dragging in Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522244/making-a-component-less-sensitive-to-dragging-in-swing)

Comment: there are three ways AWTEventListener, MouseInfo, convert Point from SwingUtilities

Comment: @mKorbel I can't link any of those to my problem. Again, I DON'T want to implement a custom click detector.

Comment: `Again, I DON'T want to` == interesting, read MouseWhatever APIs, to test with modifiers, to compare mouse_events (for Java version >1.6_030/1.7_30) with API, rest are in the Bug Parade on some Java Forums, then to call back :-)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522244/making-a-component-less-sensitive-to-dragging-in-swing

Comment: hmm .. is your problem not-receiving-a-clicked or starting-a-drag? Not they I have a solution to any of those, just for clarification :-) My guess would be that the first is a OS property that you can't change from within java/swing/awt.

Comment: @kleopatra My problem is not receiving a click because it gets translated into a tiny drag (mouseDragged() is called instead of mouseClicked()). It is not a OS property because Windows itself considers tiny drags as clicks - which doesn't necessarily imply that AWT exposes a parameter to solve this problem. It's especially frustrating in the era of retina displays on touch screens where clicking without moving the cursor at least one pixel is almost impossible.

Comment: _Windows itself considers tiny drags as clicks_ not on any of my systems ;-) In my experience, tiny drags result in the click not fired (nor a drag started) - that's why I asked and suspected a OS property. Will later try to verify, .. hmm, any idea of a action in standard native win software that are triggered by a click? (not a pressed or released)

Comment: maybe found an example: in explorer file details, press on header, drag a tiny bit and release -> column is sorted. Press and drag a bit farther, header starts to be dragged, release, header jumps back nothing sorted. That's what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the sensitivity of the D&D using:

```
System.setProperty("awt.dnd.drag.threshold", "5");
```

### Note: this is only honored by List, Table, Text and Tree components!

See usages of `javax.swing.plaf.basic.DragRecognitionSupport#mouseDragged()` method.

Comment: Exactly the kind of thing I was looking for, except it does not seem to affect mouse listeners

Comment: I can confirm this as I keep losing clicks on mouse listener in a 32x32 JPanel using  'System.setProperty("awt.dnd.drag.threshold", "100")'. Considering mouseClicked MouseEvent is a method detail of MouseDragGestureRecognizer class, this is a weird thing I guess?

Comment: This solved my problem perfectly thanks. When it initially "seemed not to work" I eventually discovered that someone's code was overwriting the x & y in the mousePressed MouseEvent to translate the coordinates (instead of copying the event first), not realizing that this was overwriting the event that the MouseDragGestureRecognizer eventually uses. Correcting that going everything working right. One can verify that this property is operating properly by breakpointing in WMouseDragGestureRecognizer mousePressed & mouseDragged.